# Nested function inside literal Object

Tags: javascript, object, function, nested, literals

if in a literal object i try to reference a function using "this" inside a nested property/function, this don't work. Why? A nested property have it's own scope?

For example, i want to call f1 from inside d.f2:

```
var object = {    

  a: "Var a",
  b: "Var b",
  c: "Var c",

  f1: function() {
    alert("This is f1");
  },

  d: {
      f2: function() {
       this.f1();
    }
  },

  e: {
      f3: function() {
        alert("This is f3");
     }
  }
}
```

object.f1();    // Work
object.d.f2();  // Don't Work.
object.e.f3();  // Work

Thanks, Andrea.

Comment: Inside f2, `this` points to `d`, not `object`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` refers to `d` inside `f2` and not `object`. You could store a reference to object, or call `object` directly, or use `call`/`apply` to call the function and explicitly tell it what `this` means inside that function:

```
object.d.f2.call(object); // now this refers to object inside f2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach which doesn't change the context of `this` inside `f2()`, based on [@slaver113's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14125233/192886):

```js
var object = (function() {
  var _this = {
    f1: function() {
      alert('This is f1');
    },
    d: {
      f2: function() {
        _this.f1();
      }
    }
  }

  return _this;
})();

object.d.f2(); // Alerts 'This is f1'
```

Comment: +1 for Module Pattern http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript